# Serial port Communication through Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am try to communicate from website to device serial port, i configured mainfest.json in chrome then in my app it showing serial' is only allowed for packaged apps, but this is a extension.

Can any tell me solution for this please .....

Comment: Isn't the error message clear enough - the platform is telling you that working with serial port cannot be done from an extension and you have to create a packaged app to be able to do that? Googling the difference between the two will give you all the answers

Comment: Do you need it for any website or just one particular website?

Comment: the solution is to make an app and use it to communicate with the extension

Comment: @ZigMandel That's one potential solution. My question is specifically to see if `externally_connectable` is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

chrome.serial API is only for apps as stated in the documentation:

- it's listed on [https://developer.chrome.com/**apps**/api_index](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index)
- it's not listed on [https://developer.chrome.com/**extensions**/api_index](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index)